# Moment JS - Get difference in millisecond

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I'm trying to subtract 2 hours with milliseconds to make a difference.

So far I have tried this, but it always returns me seconds without the milliseconds:

```
let arrivalTime = '02:23:15.1515';
let departureTime = '02:23:11.1111';

console.log('Moment arrivalTime: ' + moment(arrivalTime, 'HH:mm:ss.sss'));
console.log('Moment departureTime: ' + moment(departureTime, 'HH:mm:ss.sss'));
console.log('subtract: ' + moment(arrivalTime, 'HH:mm:ss.sss').subtract(moment(departureTime, 'HH:mm:ss.sss')))
console.log('subtract time: ' + moment(arrivalTime, 'HH:mm:ss.sss').subtract(moment(departureTime, 'HH:mm:ss.sss')).format('hh:mm:ss.sss'));
console.log('Moment difference: ' + moment(arrivalTime, 'HH:mm:ss.sss').diff(moment(departureTime, 'HH:mm:ss.sss'), 'millisecond', true));
console.log('Moment duration: ' + moment.duration(moment(arrivalTime, 'HH:mm:ss.sss').diff(moment(departureTime, 'HH:mm:ss.sss')), 'millisecond'));
```

These are the results:

> Moment arrivalTime: 1573524736000
>
> Moment departureTime: 1573524730000
>
> WARN  Deprecation warning: value provided is not in....
>
> subtract: 1573524736000
>
> subtract time: 02:12:16.1616
>
> Moment difference: 6000
>
> Moment duration: 6000

These 6000 should be something like 6783 or something like that, looks like is doing rounding.

Any help would appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is to add .SSS instead of .sss

```
let arrivalTime = '02:23:15.1515';
let departureTime = '02:23:11.1111';

console.log('Moment difference: ' + moment(arrivalTime, 'HH:mm:ss.SSS').diff(moment(departureTime, 'HH:mm:ss.SSS'), 'millisecond', true));
console.log('Moment duration: ' + moment.duration(moment(arrivalTime, 'HH:mm:ss.SSS').diff(moment(departureTime, 'HH:mm:ss.SSS')), 'millisecond'));
```